# Understanding custom Delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, delegation

So I have an app, and in the app there is a `tableView`, I have a `uinavigationbarbutton` that presents a modal `viewController`.  When the user hits a go button in the modal interface, I want it dismiss the modal view and get some of the information in the modal view.  I will than put that info in the tableView.  To do this, I wrote a custom delegate, but it doesn’t work.  I included my code below.  Thanks for any help.

TrackerMainViewController.h //the tableView

```
#import "NewItemViewController.h"
@interface TrackerMainViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, DetailDelegate>
```

TrackerMainViewController.m

```
 -(void)finishedAddingFoodItemFromDetail:(NSDate *)date whatWasEaten:(NSString *)whatFood whichMeal:(NSString *)meal {
     NSLog(@"in delegate method here");
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

NewItemViewController.h // the modal view

```
@protocol DetailDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)finishedAddingFoodItemFromDetail:(NSDate *)date whatWasEaten:(NSString *)whatFood whichMeal:(NSString *)meal;
@end

@interface NewItemViewController : UIViewController {
     id <DetailDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <DetailDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

NewItemViewController.h

```
@implementation NewItemViewController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
//the go button in the modal view

- (IBAction)Go:(id)sender {
[self.delegate finishedAddingFoodItemFromDetail:[NSDate date] whatWasEaten:@"chicken" whichMeal:@"breakfast"];
}
```

I put a log in both the go button and in the implementation of the delegate in the tableview, but only the go log is being called.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted, you dont set the delegate. You need to set it similar to this `detailView.delegate = self`, otherwise it is `nil`. You can send messages to a `nil`-object without any warning and error, nothing will happen.